# How to add content below the custom listview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hello friends please help me I am using custom listview and I want add some content below this custom listview but problem is that when I tried to add anything below this custom listview it shows nothing in below my list view here is my xml code you can check now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nightmode"
    tools:context=".ALLVERSE">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="ALL VERESE" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </ListView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_below="@+id/mylistview"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          android:text="joshua"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The text which is below the listview inside the linear layout shows nothing but above it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you list view occupies the whole layout and can't scroll to see your `TextView`. Put items below the `Toolbar` to a `Scrollbar`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nightmode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ALLVERSE">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ALL VERESE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"><!--This is the scroll view -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp">


    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mylistview"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="joshua"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, this should solve your problem:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/mylistview"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```